# How to display youtube playlist in React NatiVe?

Tags: react-native, expo, youtube-api

I want to show a youtube playlist as a list in my RN app. I found this library called codesweetly but it doesn't work. Is there another way to show a list of youtube  Videos in a similar list like youtube and the user clicks the thumbnail and it naVigates to youtube?

Here is what I haVe so far

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import YouTubePlaylist from "@codesweetly/react-youtube-playlist";

export default function Videos() {
  return(
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress((index) => naVigate({{youtubeUrl}})>
    <YouTubePlaylist
      apiKey=""
      playlistId="ID here"
      uniqueName="Playlist name"
    />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```